# .NET Core source code Decimal class: Constant in converting decimal to double explanation

Tags: c#, .net-core

In the source code of .NET `Decimal` class, there is a function named `VarR8FromDec` containing a constant variable `ds2to64` with value `1.8446744073709552e+019`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Convert Decimal to double
/// </summary>
internal static double VarR8FromDec(in decimal value)
{
    // Value taken via reverse engineering the double that corresponds to 2^64. (oleaut32 has ds2to64 = DEFDS(0, 0, DBLBIAS + 65, 0))
    const double ds2to64 = 1.8446744073709552e+019;

    double dbl = ((double)value.Low64 +
                (double)value.High * ds2to64) / s_doublePowers10[value.Scale];

    if (value.IsNegative)
        dbl = -dbl;

     return dbl;
}
```

([Decimal.DecCalc.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/c6af4cfc8b625851b91823d9be746c4f7abdc667/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Decimal.DecCalc.cs#L1888))

The comment for that constant reads:

> Value taken via reverse engineering the double that corresponds to 2^64. (oleaut32 has ds2to64 = DEFDS(0, 0, DBLBIAS + 65, 0))

I have tried looking what this means and what it's meant to do in MSDN or Google, to no avail. What does this constant represent, why does it have to be reverse engineered, and how does it affect decimal calculations in .NET?

Comment: Reverse Engineering here should bê read with a loose meaning. They didn't reverse engineered someone's code, they "reversed engineered" the value of the double 2^ 64 by checking it and writing it down as a constant.

Comment: Presumably they didn't have access to the source code for `oleaut32.dll`

Comment: Note that the 2^64 value didn't really need to be reverse engineered - if you know the IEEE 754 format for doubles, you could work out that to represent 2^64 you could use the binary unsigned long value `0b_0_10000111111_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_0000`.